# Entering Romania with a two entry Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, romania

Let's say I have a two entry Schengen visa from Greece, that is valid and both entries are unused, and I want to visit Romania.

Can I fly directly to Romania or do I have to go to Greece first, then from Greece to Romania?

Answer (score 2):

You can fly directly to Romania. A prior visit to Greece is not required.

> Starting July 11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of [Decision No 565/2014/EU](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014D0565&from=EN), Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own national visas, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of 180 days the following:
>
> - The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a Schengen member
>     state;
> - The limited territorial validity visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The short-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The long-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The long-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The residence permit issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia
> - The long-term resident's EC residence permit (the validity of which is of 5 years or more) issued by a member state of the European
>     Union.
>
> **Attention!** The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by the Schengen Member States.

Source: [Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040).